# Adding an external style sheet to Page Template Header Kentico CMS 7

Tags: kentico

I have a hopefully simple question, but I have been trying to figure this out for the past few hours with no luck and no response from Kentico's support team.

Just recently upgraded Kentico CMS from 6 to 7 and am now having problems getting css to load that used to be just called in the individual page templates. I decided to try and add in the css link at the Site Manager > Development > Page Templates > My Template > Header tab. This is apparently supposed to work according to posts on Kentico's website, but no matter what I do, I cannot get the css file to load for that template.

The link tag for the css should be formatted correctly, but in case Kentico does something crazy, here it is

```
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="../_SalesPad/Stylesheets/_HomeMini.css" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: And what if for some reason, I don't have access to admin panel? How can I insert that link directly into the header tab, or somewhere that the external style is loaded for all pages on the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working for me if I add your tag.

Could you make sure that in your masterpage on the header tab that "Allow child templates to inherit the current header" is ticked.

Comment: It was checked, but for some reason adding the css this way still is not working for me. There seems to be something wrong with either the iis settings or something in the cms desk. I am now using the css webpart though, since even the Kentico support team is not sure why it won't work.